# undefined unicode in python3

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, scrapy

I am trying to follow [scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) in scrapy (python3)
using scrapy shell "any_website"

```
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join
MapCompose(unicode.strip)([u' I',u' am\n'])
```

I am getting this error `Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

`
this is affecting my scrapy Item Loader when I use (same error happens)

```
 l = ItemLoader(item=PropertiesItem(), response=response)

 l.add_xpath('title', '//*[@itemprop="name"][1]/text()',MapCompose(unicode.strip, unicode.title))
```

the example on the scrapy docs is pretty straightforward but I am getting this error is it because I use python3 ?

Answer (score 1):

in python2.x:

```
item = unicode(item, 'utf-8')
```

in python3.x:

```
item = str(item.encode('utf-8'))
```

Python 3 renamed the unicode type to str, the old str type has been replaced by bytes
renaming unicode occurrences with str will worked

Comment: how can I use this with scrapy

Comment: @programmerwiz32 The old `unicode` type is now `str`. Thus, `unicode.strip` becomes `str.strip`.

Comment: @akash If `item` is `"a"`, your Python-3 example produces `"b'a'"`. Is that really your suggestion?